# REQUEST_DENIED using Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am developing an application for Android using the text search Google Places API. The goal is to give an address and get the latitude and longitude back so I can mark it on a map.
To do so I send the following request to Google Places :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=46+Rue+Emile+Raspail+Arcueil&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY

using this code :

```
public class GeoLocRDV {

    private LatLng pos;

    private static final String API_KEY = " xxxxx_MY_KEY ";
    private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?";

    public GeoLocRDV(String rdvPlace){
        String url;

        try {
            url = PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL+"query=" + URLEncoder.encode(rdvPlace,"UTF-8") + "&sensor=true&key=" + API_KEY;
            Log.e("DEBUG HTTP", url);

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;

            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                String responseString = out.toString();

                Log.e("DEBUG RESP", responseString);

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray results = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("results");

                Log.e("DEBUG JSON", results.toString());

                double rdvLat = (Double) results.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lat");
                Log.e("DEBUG JSON lat", Float.toString((float) rdvLat));

                double rdvLng = (Double) results.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").get("lng");
                Log.e("DEBUG JSON lng", Float.toString((float) rdvLng));

                this.pos = new LatLng(rdvLat, rdvLng);
                Log.e("DEBUG GEO", pos.toString());

            }else{
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I get this response :

```
{
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : [],
    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I tried to :

- Switch the "sensor" parameter to "true" and "false"
- Change https to http
- Verify my key was correctly copied/pasted and corresponding to the one in my manifest
- I also went to the api console, then to SERVICES, clicked Active services tab and verified 'Places API' is turned ON. Clicked on the ? and "try it out!" link next to it. It also returned me the same JSON (REQUEST_DENIED)

I read on StackOverflow I could try to change the port address to 443 to get response from Places API, but I don't know how to do it.

Finally, I specify that I activated Google Places service after getting my API KEY (because I am also using Maps API) and it is an Android key (not a server or browser), but it is not supposed to be an issue since a key works for a whole application.

I am running out of ideas to fix this request problem, so I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you certain you didn't exceed 1000 requests per day?

Comment: Yes, I made 3 requests yesterday (all failed) and 1 today. And I checked my quota on the API console, it says 0% used

Comment: If all you want to do is just do some reverse geo-location lookups, then why not try the `Geocoder` class that already built into android? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html its just a suggestion for you to deliver the result.

Comment: I didn't know about this, I'll look into it immediately, thanks for the tip, hope it will help !

Comment: Okay you were right, that's exactly what I wanted, thanks for your answer !